# Hoose meaning house?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology

How did "hoose" come to be used to mean "house"?

> **Hoose:**
>   Hoose is a disease of sheep, cattle, goats, and swine caused by the presence of various species of nematodes of the genera Dictyocaulus, Metastrongylus, and Protostrongylus in the bronchial tubes or in the lungs. It is marked by cough, dyspnea, anorexia and constipation. Also called verminous bronchitis.apv

— [Definitions.net](https://www.definitions.net/definition/Hoose)

> **Hoose:**
>   verminous bronchitis of cattle, sheep, and goats caused by larval strongylid roundworms irritating the bronchial tubes and producing a dry hacking cough
>   — called also husk, lungworm disease

— [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/hoose)

Comment: @Lawrence, I have american friend who used it to mean house. but sure https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoose here it also gives "house"

Comment: Say the two words. Your mouth goes through essentially the same motions for both, except that you open your mouth wider for "house".  Now imagine that you're really tired (or just lazy).

Comment: Works also with other _ou_-words like _mouse_ and _about_, giving us such delightful aphorisms as, _There's a moose, loose, aboot this hoose!_

Comment: The word was also used in a Maynards Wine Gums sweet advert "There's juice loose aboot this hoose" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaLsb7oHqCs

Comment: Och, ye dinna ken aboot a hoose?

Comment: @HotLicks - Or a Scot. ;-)

Comment: @spikey_richie My mind went to this old classic: [Crazy moose, loose in the hoose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkSn3e_lR94)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Pronunciation of 'house' as *hoose*:

The pronunciation /huːs/ is a remnant of Old English in some dialects of Present Day English. In Old English, 'house' was written ***hūs*** and it would've been pronounced /xuːs/<sup>**1**</sup> or /huːs/.

In Middle English, it was pronounced /h**uː**s/ (*hoose*). The [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) changed the qualities if almost all the long vowels. It changed the original long vowel of 'house' /uː/ to a diphthong /aʊ/ in most dialects; however, as the Wiki article notes, the shift didn't operate on long back vowels in Northern English because they had undergone an earlier shift. That article also says that /uː/ remained unaffected.

That article goes on to say that the long vowels /iː/, /eː/, and /oː/ in Northern English shifted, but '/uː/ in house did not'.

Here's a chart illustrating the vowel shifts:

> [image: results of GVS]
>
> [Great Vowel Shift - Wikipedia]

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoose) says the spelling 'hoose' is dialectal.

There's also a disease 'hoose', though that is with a /z/ sound at the end.

---

**NOTES:**

1. According to the [Wikipedia article on Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_phonology#Phonology), [h, ç] were the allophones of the phoneme /x/ occurring word-initially and after a front vowel, respectively. Though I'm not entirely sure, that's why I've written both /xuːs/ and /huːs/.

Answer (score 7):

***[Hoose](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/house)***, a Scottish variant of house:

> HOUSE, n., v. Also hoose (Gen.Sc.)
>
> 2. Combs.: (1) ***hoose-a-gate***, adj., gossiping from door to door (Ork. 1957), used as a v. in vbl.n., ***hooseagettan***, visiting each other's houses. Cf. (3); (2) ***hoosamenyie,*** -minya, hoose-menyie, an uproar, disturbance, quarrel (Ork. 1929 Marw.).

(History of the Scots language)

Hoose is present also in Northern   England and as [The Oxford History of English](https://books.google.it/books?id=cLB3v7csB0UC&pg=PR57&lpg=PR57&dq=northern%20english%20hoose&source=bl&ots=fMIxPpxbFJ&sig=ACfU3U3ykaWgXqldJ5NkfWowzn1SJuW6-A&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwits8WI6JfpAhWny6YKHfDNCbwQ6AEwD3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=Hoose&f=false) notes about the GVS: [image]

Comment: Without which pronunciation, [Hoots Mon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoots_Mon) would not work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two words involved in your question:

1. **House**, in standard English, pronounced /haʊs/(rhymes with "mouse") =  a dwelling place.

1a. **Hoose**, in the Scottish and Northeastern English dialects, pronounced /huːs/ (rhymes with "noose") =  a dwelling place.

(There are many other spellings of dialect versions of "house", one of which is 19th century Irish English "hooze")

2. **Hoose** or **hooze**, in in standard English, pronounced /huːz/ (rhymes with "whose") - a disease of sheep.

Comment: I think you should provide sources and links to your answer.

Comment: @Hatchi: The source is myself - a native speaker who is conversant with both the word "house" and Scottish and Northeastern accents . (There are no technicalities here) As far as diseases of sheep are concerned - the OP gave that. ++The IPA is mine.

Comment: Fine, but with all due respect, nobody is a “source” on ELU, apart from very rare exceptions. Sources need to be cited and links have to be provided. That’s how the site works.

Comment: @Hachi: Whereas I see your broader point. I have noted that in many, if not all, answers, there is a point at which stated facts are accepted without exterior authority - who could be a greater authority than you or I on how to say "house" or what it means? Or how the Scots say "house"? ++ I have also noted that the "very rare exceptions" are also challenged.

Comment: That’s why reliable sources are always helpful. That’s what the site  rules warmly recommend. Here is the list - https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available

Comment: This answer is fine, and the fanaticism with which some ELU users demand a "source" for each simple answer sucks. After all, @Hachi, you'd be surprised but the "sources" that inspired the dictionary entries whose inclusion you ask for were none else but native speakers of English, such ad Greybeard.

Comment: There's a very simple answer to this. You simply give *yourself* as the source. E.g.  "As a native speaker, I can tell you the following:".  That is good practice because then we know that the answer hasn't just been copy/pasted from somewhere else. You have explicitly said that it is a product of your own experience and knowledge and that is perfectly acceptable..